# Proper way of handling reference to NSError

Tags: objective-c, nserror

My code looks like this, sometimes app crashes on the last line, when it tries to log the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
BOOL isDir;
NSError *error;
NSString *downloadPath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [download downloadFolder], [download escapedTitle]] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:downloadPath isDirectory:&isDir])
{
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:downloadPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I've also attached the output from the console:
[image]

Comment: @Wain Although that might work for most practical purposes, it is not guaranteed to work, as the pointer may be changed to an invalid value during the execution of the method. The value of `error` will only be valid if the method returns `NO`.

Comment: @gaige True, it shouldn't happen but it indeed could.

Comment: @Wain No, there is no reason to initialize the `error` pointer to `nil` and it is never valid to use `if (error) ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cocoa, the `NSError **` is only valid if the called method returns an error, which in this case would be if `-createDirectoryAtPath:...` returns false.

Instead of testing for `if (error)`, test for the return value of the `-createDirectoryAtPath:` method being false, and you'll be good to go.

For example:

```
if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:downloadPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: So this is a better method? if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:downloadPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error])
                            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

Comment: Yes, I was just adding that to my answer ;-)

Comment: In this case also check if NSArray is created? `NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *downloads = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:allDownloads error:&error];`

Comment: In the case of `executeFetchRequest:error:`, you need to check for `downloads` being `nil`.  If it is `nil`, then `error` will be valid, otherwise it is undefined.